# Tensor product in vector spaces 2

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces. Assume the $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ are linearly independent in $V.$

I try to prove the following result

If $$\sum\limits_{i} a_i \otimes b_i = 0$$ then $b_i = 0$ for any $i\in I.$ Here $a_i \otimes b_i\in V \otimes W.$

Thanks for all hints!

Comment: Hint: Write $$a_i \otimes b_i = \text{vec}(b_i a_i^{\mathsf{T}}),$$ where $\text{vec}$ is the vectorization operator.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Express each $b_i$ as a linear combination of basis elements of $W$, and note that if $\{e_i\}$ is a linearly independent set over $V$ and $\{f_j\}$ is a linearly independent set over $W$, then $\{e_i\otimes f_j\}$ is a linearly independent set over $V\otimes W$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a linear independent set, we can extend this set to a full basis of $V$: $\{a_i\}_{i\in J}$.

Define the functional $f_{i}:V\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ on $\{a_i\}_{i\in J}$ by 
 $\ f_{i}(a_i)=1$ and $f_{i}(a_j)=0$ and extend by linearity to the whole $V$.

Finally, if $\sum_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i=0$ then $0=f_j\otimes Id(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_j(a_i)b_i=b_j$.